# Undo Jquery conditional statement

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a conditional statement for responsive design that places a logo in the middle of the menu if the screen size is bigger then 1018px.

How can I undo that statement or say if screen size is less then or equal to 1017 put the logo back in its original position?

Here is what I have so far, which does not seem to work:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 1018) {
            $('.menu-item-5302').after($('.at_middle'));
        }
      if ($(window).width() <= 1017) {
        //this doesnt work
        $( ".at_middle" ).detach();
        $( ".at_middle" ).append("l-header");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the updated code!

```
`at_middle` is a logo 
`menu-item-5302` is a `<li>` tag 
`l-header` is a header
```

Comment: Are you appending the logo?  Is the logo there all the time anyways?

Comment: _"How can I undo that statement or say if screen size is less then or equal to 1017 put the logo back in its original position?"_ What is "original position" ? Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: @ntgCleaner  the logo is always there in my theme it is located on top of the menu to restyle it without touching the html i must use jquery and css. First i put it inbetwen the primary menu. so i have 2 <li> on each side of the logo but in mobile or tablet i want to undo or put it back to the original position ontop of the menu

Comment: Can you make the CSS for both positions, then just change the CSS?  I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: @ntgCleaner i can't because the logo needs to be under a different parent

Comment: @RajaSharma: There isn't really an "undo".  But what you *can* do is update the DOM/styling/etc. any way that you want.  So what is the update that you want to make?  In what way do you need to change the page?

Comment: _"Here is the updated code!"_ Can include `html` at Question ? , create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Why don't you just put two logos with display toggling depending specific CSS media querie (which anyway would be more relevant than checking for `$(window).width()` regarding viewport width)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `.remove()` Also, the conditional can be cleaned up - If it's greater than 1018 do something, else do something else.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1018) {
        $('.menu-item-5302').after($('.at_middle'));
    } else {
        $('.at_middle').remove();
    }
});
```

**UPDATED**

Here's an example of my comment above.  To do this properly, give the logo a general class name such as `.logo` then make 2 CSS classes that control where the logo needs to be (center or left aligned)

```
.logo {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
}
.logo.left {
    /* Position your logo with CSS Here, below is an example */
    float:left;
}
.logo.center {
    /* Position your logo with CSS Here, below is an example */
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px; /*this is how to center with relative */
}
```

then with your jQuery, you just add and remove classes:

```
function moveLogo() {
    var windowW = $(window).width();
    if(windowW > 1018){
        $('.logo').removeClass('left');
        $('.logo').addClass('center');
    } else {
        $('.logo').removeClass('center');
        $('.logo').addClass('left');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    moveLogo();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    moveLogo();
});
```

Having this on Doc.ready and window.resize will make sure that the function to position the logo is working when the page loads AND when the page resizes.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**
So, since you need to show a different logo in a different location, try this:

```
function moveLogo() {
    var winW = $(window).width();
    if(winW > 1018) {
        logo.hide();
        logoClone.show();
    } else {
        logo.show();
        logoClone.hide();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var logo = $('.logo');
    var logoClone = logo.clone();
    $('.menu-item-5302').after(logoClone);
    logoClone.hide();
    moveLogo();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    moveLogo();
});
```

This latest code will clone your logo (so you only need one instance of it to begin with) then append it where you'd like it and hide it for when it's ready.  Then depending on window size, it will show or hide the right logo.

Comment: I don't want to remove the logo i want to put it back over the primary menu but i always get an error saying it already exists in the parent as a child

Comment: @RajaSharma, Updated

Comment: I see, so you need to show a different logo in a different location

Comment: i need to show the same logo in a different location depending on the screen size. I cannot edit the html so jquery is needed to move the element from child to child and parent to grandparent @ntgCleaner

Comment: @RajaSharma, Updated -

Comment: Just as a side note, checking for `$(window).width();` is(could be) wrong regarding relevant viewport width. Using [window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) is preferred method

Answer (score 1):

**I have updated my answer to a cleaner solution:**

```
jQuery(function($) {


    $(document).ready(function() {

      var logo = $('.at_middle');
      var pos1 = $('.menu-item-5302');
      var pos2 = $('.l-header');

      pos1.after($('.at_middle').clone());

      if ($(window).width() > 1018) {

         pos1.next('.at_middle').show();
         pos2.find('.at_middle').hide();

      }else if ($(window).width() <= 1017) {

         pos1.next('.at_middle').hide();
         pos2.find('.at_middle').show);

      }
});
```

**Even simpler:**

```
jQuery(function($) {


    $(document).ready(function() {

      var logo = $('.at_middle');
      var pos1 = $('.menu-item-5302');



         pos1.after($('.at_middle').clone());

         });

 });
```

CSS

```
.at_middle{ display:none; }

@media(max-width:1017px){
    .menu-item-5302 .at_middle{

       display:block;

     }
}

@media(min-width:1018px){
    .l-header .at_middle{

       display:block;

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.insertAfter()` , `.clone()` , `css()`

```
    function logo() {
        if ($(window).width() > 1018) {
            // set original element `display` to `none`
            $(".menu-item-5302")
            .css("display", "none")
            // clone original element
            .clone(false)
            // move clone after `.at_middle`
            .insertAfter($(".at_middle"))
            // set clone `display` to `block`
            .css("display", "block");
        }
        if ($(window).width() <= 1017) {
            // undo the code of previous if statement
            // set clone `display` to `none`
            $(".at_middle + .menu-item-5302")
            .css("display", "none");
             // set original element `display` to `block`
             $(".menu-item-5302:first")
            .css("display", "block")

        }
    }

    $(document).ready(logo); $(window).resize(logo);
```